# What's the correct way to add a PageContent/ FixedPage to a FixedDocument in WPF?

Tags: wpf, document, fixeddocument

In WPF, in order to add a `FixedPage` to a `FixedDocument` in code one needs to:

```
var page = new FixedPage();
var pageContent = new PageContent();

((IAddChild)pageContent).AddChild(page);
```

This appears to be the only way, however:

- The MSDN documentation explicitly says one shouldn't do this ('This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code.'- [PageContent.IAddChild.AddChild Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb495750.aspx)).
- It's ugly to have to cast to an explicit interface implementation in order to add the content to `PageContent`.
- It's not simple to perform the basic operation of `PageContent`.

The documentation doesn't actually explain how to do this and I couldn't find any other information on how to do it.  Is there another way?  A 'correct' way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to MSDN documentation, you simply add a `FixedPage` object to the `PageContent.Child` property and then add that to the `FixedDocument` by calling the  `FixedDocument.Pages.Add` method.

For instance:

```
public FixedDocument RenderDocument() 
{
    FixedDocument fd = new FixedDocument();
    PageContent pc = new PageContent();
    FixedPage fp = new FixedPage();
    TextBlock tb = new TextBlock();

    //add some text to a TextBox object
    tb.Text = "This is some test text";
    //add the text box to the FixedPage
    fp.Children.Add(tb);
    //add the FixedPage to the PageContent 
    pc.Child = fp;
    //add the PageContent to the FixedDocument
    fd.Pages.Add(pc);

    return fd;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, where's the documentation?

Comment: Check out the example at the bottom of this page:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.pagecontent%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: when writing pc.Child it shows error. its a get method not set

Comment: The MSDN documentation says the `PageContent.Child` property "Gets or **sets** the FixedPage associated with this PageContent."  Here's the link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.pagecontent.child(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The `PageContent.Child` property supports both `get` and `set` at .NET 4 but only `get` at .NET 3.5

Comment: Try this:- ((System.Windows.Markup.IAddChild)pageContent).AddChild(fixedPage);

Comment: what about PageContent.Source ? "The <PageContent> element has a single required attribute, Source, which refers to a FixedPage part"